# how to differentiate parent and child tag while xml parsing in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to get all tags values from xml and want to store them in a `NSMutableDictionary`. I am having a problem to store the values in the `NSMutableDictionary`, I have a `NSMutableArray` with a `NSMutableDictionary` instead.

Comment: So what is the problem you want help with, or the code that has the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally your tags are unique, something like this:

```
<widgets>
    <widget>
        <wname>My Widget</wname>
        <wcost>1.75</wcost>
    </widget>
    <widget>
        <wname>My Other Widget</wname>
        <wcost>3.57</wcost>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

So what that would translate to is an Array of Dictionaries with each Dictionary having two Key Value Pairs (KVP's).

If you want more help, you will need to post a sample of the XML you are trying to parse and the code you are using to try and parse it.